# Can we hide <table><tr> in responsive website

Tags: responsive-design, html-table, media-queries

I've one question. At this time on my page I've :

```
<table><tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr></table>
```

When my page is resized under 1024px, I would like to hide a

`<table><tr>
</tr></table>`

What can I add here ->

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px  {
...
}
```

Comment: can we have a similar result of
<table><tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr></table>


with <div> ???

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 @media screen and (max-width: 1024px  {
      #myTable {display:none;}
 }
```